# Spring MVC after calling webservice at Rest Controller and returning xml response how can I execute other function after response sent?

Tags: java, spring, rest, scheduled-tasks

Using Spring MVC I have a webservice that receives several parameters and inserts them to the Database returning to the client the id of inserted row. How can I execute other function after the id has been sent to the client? How can I schedule a method to run after the webservice return?

Answer (score 0):

Spring supports `@Async` annotation.

Which means any call to the annotated method returns immediately.  Hence you could call the method right before you return the response from your controller.

Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled) for more details.

Another way is to use AOP and create a thread that handles the after response possessing!

Comment: Hi Amanuel, thank you for your answer. I've done it with a TaskScheduler. It seems to be working. I've set it for a few moments later. Just for the other part to have time to receive the id that I sent on the response so that I can work with it from then on. I'll see how the Async works and if it's a better approach for this case.